# Sort Coordinates in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of coordinates like:

[44.64,-123.11;38.91,-121.99;40.35,-122.28;43.21,-123.36;41.77,-122.58;37.77,-122.42]

I need to sort this list. Any suggestions ?

EDIT:
Sorry for not sharing the expected output:

It should be [44.64,-123.11;43.21,-123.36;41.77,-122.58;40.35,-122.28;38.91,-121.99;37.77,-122.42]

Comment: in order to sort anything you need a sorting order (for example, alphabetically, chronologically, by distance, etc.). Which logic would you use to sort your list ?

Comment: How do you sort coordinates? What's your expected output?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
li = [44.64,-123.11;38.91,-121.99;40.35,-122.28;43.21,-123.36;41.77,-122.58;37.77,-122.42]
```

Your "list" looks more like a `string`, with ";" and "," to separate 2D points and their values. I imagine that you want a `list` of tuples, that represent the x and y coordinates? So first you need to split your `string` into a `list`

```
li = li.split(';')
```

Now you have a `list` of `string`s, that you need to split into pairs of `float` values. You can do that with two list comprehensions

```
li = [(float(a.split(',')[0]), float(a.split(',')[1])) for a in li]
```

Now you have a `list` of coordinates that you could sort in some way. Maybe smallest `x` first or something. Use Python's `sorted` build-in function to do that, e.g.

```
sorted_li = sorted(li, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

The docs are here, read them.

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#sorted

Comment: Indeed. Note that if you want to sort by `x` first, you don't need to specify any `key` for sorted.